# Como ordenar três divs de acordo com um atributo dela?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho 3 divs:

```
<div id='pai'>
    <div class='produtos' contagem='2'></div>
    <div class='produtos' contagem='1'></div>
    <div class='produtos' contagem='3'></div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de trocá-los de lugar, de forma que as divs com o atributo **contagem** de maior numero ficassem primeiro(em ordem decrescente).

Como consigo isso de maneira que os números da contagem eu desconheço, ou seja, eles podem não ser esses que passei como exemplo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode extrair uma array das divs com o jQuery e ordená-lo com o método [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
var divList = $(".produtos");
divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    // para ordem decrescente; use a - b para crescente
    return $(b).attr("contagem") - $(a).attr("contagem")
});
$("#pai").html(divList);
```

---

**Fonte**: [SOEn - Javascript/jQuery: Reordering divs according to data-attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14438439/664577)

Comment: Detalhe: com esse método, eventuais listeners de eventos nessa divs serão perdidos.

Answer (score 6):

Eu sugiro, por segurança clonar os elementos e voltar a inseri-los no HTML:

```
var novosElementos = $('#pai div').get().sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('contagem') - b.getAttribute('contagem')
}).map(function(el){
    return $(el).clone(true)[0];
});
$('#pai').html(novosElementos);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x78Lwomu/

Comment: Ou, mais seguro ainda: `.clone(true, true)`

Answer (score 5):

Como a pergunta inclui a tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), deixo aqui uma solução em JS puro, com os passos comentados, para quem quiser resolver o mesmo problema sem jQuery:

```js
// Seleciona as divs que queremos ordenar
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#pai .produtos');

// Converte a NodeList de divs para array
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#How_can_I_convert_NodeList_to_Array.3F
var ordem = [].map.call(divs, function(element) {
    return element;
});

// Ordena a array pelo atributo 'contagem'
ordem.sort(function(a,b) {
    var ca = parseInt(a.getAttribute('contagem'), 10);
    var cb = parseInt(b.getAttribute('contagem'), 10);
    return cb - ca;
});

// Reinsere os filhos no pai, resultando na ordem desejada
var container = document.querySelector('#pai');
for(var i=0; i<ordem.length; i++) {
    container.appendChild(ordem[i]);   
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
    <div class="produtos" contagem="2">2</div>
    <div class="produtos" contagem="1">1</div>
    <div class="produtos" contagem="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

- Obtenha todos valores do atributo contagem das divs;
- Ordene o array;
- Ajuste a ordem na tela.

O script ficaria assim:

```
var $pai = $("#pai");
var arrProdutos = [];

$("div[contagem]", $pai).each(function() {
    arrProdutos.push( parseInt($(this).attr("contagem")) );
});

arrProdutos.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < arrProdutos.length; i++) {
    $pai.append($("div[contagem='" + arrProdutos[i] + "']", $pai));
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rot5pgvt/embedded/result/)